# $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{\|g\|_1\leq 1}|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}fg\,d x|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $0<\|f\|_\infty<\infty$ and $f$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^d$. then show $$\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{\|g\|_1\leq 1} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}fg \, dx\right|.$$

Since $|\int fg\,dx| \leq \|f\|_\infty \int|g| \, dx = \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_\infty$, I have $$\|f\|_\infty\geq\sup_{\|g\|_1\leq 1} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} fg \, dx \right|.$$

But I'm having trouble to show the opposite direction. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\vert f \vert_\infty$, for every $\varepsilon$ there exists a set of positive measure $A$ such that on $A$, $\vert f\vert \geq \vert f \vert_\infty -\varepsilon$.

We can assume that the measure of $A$ is finite (if not intersect $A$ with a large ball) .

Let $g= 1_A \cdot {1\over \mu (A)}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(f) $, (where $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ is 1 if $f$ is positive and $-1$ if $f$ is negative.

Then $\int \vert g\vert =1$ and  $\int fg \, d\mu \geq \vert f \vert_\infty -\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary and without restriction $\|f\|_\infty = C > 0$. There is a measurable set E of positive measure such that $f1_E \ge (C - \varepsilon)1_E$ (or $f1_E \le (-C + \varepsilon)1_E$). Set $\delta = \lambda(E)$ ($\lambda$ is the Lebegue measure). Define $g(x)=1_E(x)/\delta$. Then $\|g\|_1 =1$ and $|\int fg dx| \ge (C-\varepsilon)|\int g\, dx| = C - \varepsilon$.

Comment: Same proof as below, but you should assume $E$ of finite measure.

Comment: That is right thanks.